# React Component Library - How can I extend Pages as in Nuxt Module?

Tags: reactjs, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a main portal project written in nuxt 3 and there are 2 module projects (one React one Nuxt 3) under the main portal project. I couldn't find a way to add/extend pages in the React project, which I solved with a few lines in the Nuxt module.

Basically I want to handle pages/routes in modules without creating a route or a page in the main portal project. I did this very easily in nuxt project but I couldn't find solution for React.

Here is the module.ts file of the nuxt module(I removed unnecessary lines):

```
import {
  defineNuxtModule,
  addPlugin,
  createResolver,
  addComponent,
  installModule,
  extendPages,
} from "@nuxt/kit";

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
  meta: {
    name: "@halil/demo-module",
    configKey: "demoModule",
  },
  async setup(options, nuxt) {

    const { resolve } = createResolver(import.meta.url);

    // Transpile runtime
    const runtimeDir = fileURLToPath(new URL("./runtime", import.meta.url));
    nuxt.options.build.transpile.push(runtimeDir);

    // Define pages
    extendPages((pages) => {
      pages.push({
        name: "module/page-one",
        path: "/module/page-one",
        file: resolve("./runtime/pages/module/page-one.vue"),
      });
      pages.push({
        name: "module/page-two",
        path: "/module/page-two",
        file: resolve("./runtime/pages/module/page-two.vue"),
      });
    });

    addPlugin(resolve(runtimeDir, "plugin"));
  },
});

declare module "@nuxt/schema" {
  interface ConfigSchema {
    publicRuntimeConfig?: {
      demoModule?: ModuleOptions;
    };
  }
}
```

Thanks to these definations, when I add this module to the main project, when I go to **module/page-one**, the page I defined in the module is loaded. I need to do the same in the react module.

As far as I can see, they are wrapping and presenting the application with a wrapper in react with react-router-dom, but that's not what I'm looking for.

There must be a method for the module where I can manually add and define pages and routes.